# The padding argument in the proof of NTIME(n) ⊆ DTIME(n^1.2) implies Σ2-TIME(n^8) ⊆ NTIME(n^9.6)

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, proof-techniques, complexity-classes

In "Computational Complexity, A modern approach", Arora & Barak proof the following claim (Claim 5.11.2):

> Suppose that $\mathsf{NTIME}(n) \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(n^{1.2})$. Then $\Sigma_2$-$\mathsf{TIME}(n^{8})  \subseteq \mathsf{NTIME}(n^{9.6})$,

which they prove in the following way:

- If $L \in \Sigma_2$-$\mathsf{TIME}(n^8)$, then $\exists$ TM $M$ which runs in time $O(|x|^8)$ s.t.
  $x \in L \leftrightarrow \exists u \in \{0,1\}^{c|x|^8} \forall v \in 
  \{0,1\}^{d|x|^8} M(x,u,v) = 1$
- But if $\mathsf{NTIME}(n) \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(n^{1.2})$, then

> by a simple padding argument, we have a deterministic algorithm $D$ that on inputs $x, u$ with $|x| = n$ and $|u| = cn^8$ runs in time $O((n^8)^{1.2}) = O(n^{9.6})$ and returns $1$ iff there exists some $v \in \{0,1\}^{dn^8}$ such that $M(x,u,v) = 0$

I struggle to see what this "simple padding argument" might be? That is, how do we get respective deterministic algorithm $D$ if we have the TM $M$?

Comment: Isn't it clear enough that standard padding technique is able to demonstrate that $DTIME(n^{1.2})\supseteq NTIME(n)\implies DTIME(n^{9.6})\supseteq NTIME(n^8)$? **Hint**: $D$ mimics $M$ by first padding the input length to $n^8$ (with trailing dummy symbols) then enters the start state of $M$ and runs $M$ on the padded input.

Comment: Then $D$ will play the role of a de-quantifier machine that peels off the $\forall v$ quantifier for you.

Comment: @ThinhD.Nguyen I believe it should imply $DTIME(n^{9.6}) \supseteq coNTIME(n^8)$.

Answer (score 2):

The language 
$$L_1 = \{(x,u) ~|~ \exists v\in \{0,1\}^{d|x|^8}M(x,u,v) = 0\}$$ belongs to $NTIME(n)$ by design, since $|v| = O(|x| + |u|) = O(|x|^{8})$. By the assumption of the theorem, $L_1$ is decidable by some deterministic $D$ in $O((|x|+|u|)^{1.2}) = O(|x|^{9.6})$ steps. The recipee for $D$ isn't important, but the existence of such algorithm $D$ leads to the last step of the proof.